# In italiano, è permesso utilizzare due preposizioni di seguito?

Tags: prepositions

Mi riferisco per esempio a frasi del tipo:

“Parliamo di da cosa travestirci per carnevale”,

“Discutono su di chi sia quel vestito”,

“Sarà disponibile a partire da tra venti minuti“.

Sono espressioni accettabili o è sempre necessario intervenire con una perifrasi (rischiando di appesantire eccessivamente la frase)?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Non è detto che si appesantisca: “Tra venti minuti sarà disponibile” etc.

Comment: Perlomeno la combinazione "preposizione impropria" + "preposizione propria" si usa di sicuro in italiano: vedi [qui](http://www.viv-it.org/schede/preposizioni-improprie-avverbi-come-preposizioni-locuzioni-preposizionali), per esempio, "dopo di te". Forse la domanda si riferisce soltanto alle preposizioni proprie.

Comment: Esempi di "su di" se ne trovano tantissimi, ma con "su" con il ruolo di avverbio.

Comment: Su [questa pagina](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000443.jpg) del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* appare questa citazione di Foscolo: «Su di che  lascio che i vostri parolai dissertino 
ampollosamente in più pagine». Se si può dire "dissertare su di che", penso che anche si possa dire "discutere su di chi".

Comment: Ecco un'[altra citazione](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00001121.jpg) de *I promessi sposi* di Manzoni: «Su di che la madre e la  figlia facevan cento congetture, senza mai  dar nel segno, anzi senza neppure andarci vicino.»

Comment: Per quanto riguarda la combinazione "di da", ho trovato alcuni esempi sul GDLI, ma sono tutti di autori medioevali o rinascimentali.

Comment: Non sono sicuramente di uso comune e anche se “corrette” eviterei di usarle.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con te, @Gio. La mia impressione (ma si tratta soltanto dell'impressione personale di una non-italiana) dopo aver visto tutti questi esempi del GDLI è che, sebbene non si possa dire che tali combinazioni non siano ammissibili in italiano poiché alcuni autori le hanno usate, conferiscono alla frase una sintassi contorta che, se non sei un poeta o un grande scrittore, penso sia meglio evitare.

Comment: Mi viene in mente questo esempio: "Per di qua". - non ne sono sicuro, ma credo che anche in questo caso "Per" sia praticamente un avverbio.

Comment: Negli esempi che fate, perlopiù, le due preposizioni – se anche sono preposizioni – hanno un senso complessivo unico (per esempio “su di” è spesso solo un modo più ricercato per dire “su”: “Su di noi, nemmeno una nuvola” = “su noi, nemmeno una nuvola”); mentre in espressioni come quelle menzionate dall'OP le due preposizioni appartengono a sintagmi diversi (discutono **su** un argomento, e l'argomento è “**di** chi è il vestito”).

Comment: @DaG: Ma non è la stessa cosa negli esempi del Foscolo e del Manzoni? O forse non ho capito questi esempi?

Answer (score 5):

Anche tre, se si desidera:

> D’in su la vetta della torre antica,
>   Passero solitario, alla campagna
>   Cantando vai finchè non more il giorno;
>   Ed erra l’armonia per questa valle.

(Giacomo Leopardi, “Il passero solitario”)

Ma non siamo Giacomo Leopardi e questo tipo di costruzione può avere un risultato molto meno piacevole.

Per esempio,

> Parliamo di da cosa travestirci per carnevale

è pesante e goffo. Magari esce nel parlato se non si ha tempo di costruire una frase più scorrevole come

> Parliamo di come travestirci per carnevale

La frase

> Discutono su di chi sia quel vestito

è indubitabilmente corretta “discutere su” è seguito da un'interrogativa indiretta che, per caso, comincia con una preposizione. Magari non è bellissima stilisticamente, ma non è scorretta.

Diverso è il caso di

> Sarà disponibile a partire da tra venti minuti

dove il burocratese fa capolino:

> Sarà disponibile tra venti minuti

significa la stessa cosa con tre parole in meno. L'obiezione è che così non si mette in chiaro che la disponibilità prosegue anche oltre. Burocratese meno contorto:

> La disponibilità del prodotto comincerà tra venti minuti

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, quelle frasi non sono corrette, ecco la correzione di esse con una breve spiegazione a lato.

> <del>“Parliamo di da cosa travestirci per carnevale.”</del> ma
>   "Stiamo parlando di come potremmo vestirci a carnevale."

**Note**: "di da" non si usa mai.

> <del>“Discutono su di chi sia quel vestito.”</del> ma
>   "Stanno discutendo di chi sia quel vestito. "

**Note**: "su di chi" in questo contesto "su" è inutile. Una frase in cui è utilizzato "su" è invece: "La verità su di lui è che..."

> <del>“Sarà disponibile a partire da tra venti minuti.“</del> ma
>   "Sarà disponibile a partire da trenta minuti." OR "Sarà disponibile tra trenta minuti."

**Note**: Anche qui "da tra" non si usa mai.

Comment: "Discutono su di chi sia quel vestito” mi pare perfettamente normale (oltre che corretto), mentre "Stanno discutendo di chi sia quel vestito" è proprio sbagliato (da quando un vestito è una persona?).  Le altre frasi in effetti sono in qualche modo slegate.